# Как сделать из квадратного div`a треугольный?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Как можно сделать из `div 1` (квадрат) `div 2` (треугольник)?

Схема:

[image]

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css
Здесь есть все необходимые примеры, успехов

Answer (score 11):

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 200px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id=rectangle></div>
<br>
<div id=triangle-topleft></div>
```

Источник: [геометрические фигуры на CSS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/).

Comment: @zloctb, меня тоже интересует этот вопрос. А как сделать, чтобы треугольник был с рамкой, а не просто одного цвета?

Comment: для этого есть SVG. HTML и CSS придумывали не для рисования

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону css в принципе вот что за 5 минут сотворил:

```css
.up {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 200px 300px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  float: left;
}

.up p {
  text-align: left;
  top: -190px;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 93px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <p>Ваш текст в трегуольнике Ваш текст в трегуольнике
    <p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TRuQc/92/